# How to deploy Dynamcis 365 Synapse configuraiton from DEV to TEST Environment

Tags: azure, microsoft-dynamics, azure-synapse, dynamics-crm-365

1. I have D365 DEV Environment and I setup Azure Synapse Link for Dataverse with Azure Synapse Workspace.
2. I have created many new views on the DEV Synapse Workspace

Now

1. I want to deploy those configuration to TEST and SIT environment

How can I atuomate this?

I don't know if it is possible to automate this

Answer (score 0):

You want to set CI\CD for Synapse.

First step, configure source control for your dev environment. You can use Github or Azure DevOps. Except from saving version of your code and be able to work with multiple developers, your code is saved in a way ready for moving to another environment is the next step.

On how to set up source control with Synapse. please see the detailed steps here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/cicd/source-control

Second step, set up a release pipeline to move the code from one environment to the other. Detailed steps here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/cicd/continuous-integration-delivery